# Paginition refresh issue in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am showing items using pagination in AngularJS.

For example, I have 12 items and number of items per page is 5. So I have 3 pages to show with the first two pages have 5 items each and the last page has two items.

When I switch pages, say from page-1 to page-2, all 10 items from both page-1 and page-2 are displayed together for a while first before the page-2 items are displayed.

Same thing happened from page-2 to page-3, all 7 items from both page-2 and page-3 are displayed together for a while first before the page-3 items are displayed.

Whenever I switch pages, the same thing is observed.

What could be wrong?

My code is as follow.

```
                html

                <div class="adds-wrapper">
                    <div ng-show="Available">
                        <div class="item-list" ng-repeat="hotel in pagedItems[currentPage]">
                     <!-- this is how items are displayed -->      
                </div>

               <div class="pagination-bar">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                            <a class="pagination-btn" href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a></li>
                        <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)" ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage()">
                            <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                            <a class="pagination-btn" href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>



Javascript

function groupToPages() {
        $scope.pagedItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            var j = Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage);
            if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                $scope.pagedItems[j] = [$scope.filteredItems[i]];
            } else {
                $scope.pagedItems[j].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

var loadPagination = function () {
    $scope.sortingOrder = $scope.sortingOrder;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.filteredItems = [];
    $scope.groupedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = $scope.HotelAndResorts;
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.HotelAndResorts;
    $scope.hotelAvailable = true;
    if ($scope.HotelAndResorts) {
        if ($scope.HotelAndResorts.length == 0) {
            $scope.hotelAvailable = false;
            $scope.errorMessage = "No Post Found.";
        }
    } else {
        $scope.hotelAvailable = false;
        $scope.errorMessage = "No Post Found."
    }
    /*var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
        if (!needle) {
            return true;
        }
        return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };*/
    groupToPages();

    $scope.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    $scope.sort_by = function (newSortingOrder) {
        if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

        $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

        // icon setup
        $('th i').each(function () {
            // icon reset
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
        });
        if ($scope.reverse)
            $('th.' + new_sorting_order + ' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
        else
            $('th.' + new_sorting_order + ' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you paginate after updating the paged items try calling $scope.apply() this tells AngularJS to look fixup various javascript things.  Angular does some sorcery under the hood to make Javascript behave asynchronously, apply makes thing sync up.  I'm oversimplifying, if you like you can read the exact documentation, but I find when htis kind of thing happens 95% of the time it's because I didn't apply.

Comment: thank you. I am not very familiar with web applications. Should I apply at html or at javascript. If in javascript, where should I apply?